# jQuery hoverIntent Plugin show / hide div on parent hover, but keep showing when hovered

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I have a button that when hovered over (mouseover) displays a div right below it.  When hovered away (mouseout), the div disappears.

This all works well and nicely, but now I need to keep the div below the button showing if user hovers over that div (to interact with the content inside the div).

Right now this is not possible since the div will disappear immediately after you hover away from the button that triggers the div to display.

I'm using the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) jQuery Plugin to accomplish this.

```
// This is the button that when hovered
// triggers the div below it to show
$('#hoverMeToShowHideDiv').hoverIntent(function () {

$("#displayDiv").stop().slideDown('slow');
},
function () {
    // I don't want the div to hide if user hovers over it
    $("#displayDiv").stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="hoverMeToShowHideDiv"> // some stuff </div>
<div id="displayDiv"> 
    // some other stuff that I want to 
    // keep showing if users hover over it 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm open to solutions that don't involve the hoverIntent plugin

Comment: Could you post your html as well? Or, even better, a live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), demo?

Comment: David I added the html (pretty simple, really) but got it to work after applying @box9 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick another div `#wrapperDiv` around both the button and the `#displayDiv` and attach hoverIntent to `#wrapperDiv` rather than the button:

```
$('#wrapperDiv').hoverIntent(function () {
   $("#displayDiv").stop().slideDown('slow');
},
function () {
   // I don't want the div to hide if user hovers over it
   $("#displayDiv").stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapperDiv">
   <div id="hoverMeToShowHideDiv"> // some stuff </div>
   <div id="displayDiv"> 
      // some other stuff that I want to 
      // keep showing if users hover over it 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: easy and beautiful solution, thanks a ton! funny I didn't even think of it.