# Slide Left, Slide Right on parent hover and keep inner content visible

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a menu system that slides left on mouseover (or hover) of parent element and slides right on mouseout - but that also ensures that the element that slides out is accessible as it will contain a menu of options for the user.

My html is;

```
<div id="sidebarDiv">

  <div id="slidemenuDiv">

    cont here must be accessible

  </div>

</div>
```

I've found somewhat of a solution in this thread: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485669/jquery-hoverintent-plugin-show-hide-div-on-parent-hover-but-keep-showing-when) but this is for a slide up and slide down scenario. Also I noticed that the animation was a little buggy - after several mouseover/mouseout events the inner div elements height would change and you would need to refresh the page to reset it.

I have been also trying to adapt code found at: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide without much luck.

Any suggestions of where I might look? Or how to adapt the following code to work in a slide left and slide right fashion;

```
    $("#slidemenuDiv").hide();
$('#sidebarDiv').hoverIntent(function () {

   $("#slidemenuDiv").stop().slideDown('slow');

},
function () {
   // I don't want the div to hide if user hovers over it
   $("#slidemenuDiv").stop().fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Here is an example image that might explain what I am trying to achieve better;

http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/460/unled1xw.jpg

Thank you
W

## **UPDATE:**

I managed to get the following to work;

```
$("#slidemenuDiv").stop().hide();
$("#sidebarDiv").hoverIntent(
        function () {
           $("#slidemenuDiv").stop().show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
        },
        function () {
           $("#slidemenuDiv").stop().hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
        }
);
```

But the caveat being I have to include the following;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
```

Seems like a heck of a lot just for a simple slideLeft, slideRight scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Quite unclear on what you exactly want.

But from the script you posted couldn't you do something like:

```
$("#slidemenuDiv").hide();

$('#sidebarDiv').hoverIntent(
        function () {
           $("#slidemenuDiv").stop().animate({ left: '-=50'});
        },
        function () {
           $("#slidemenuDiv").stop().animate({ left: '+=50'});
        }
);
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in there, to do with the single quotes.

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your response. I tried that but I got no result. I have included an example image above that might help explain what I am trying to achieve.